# Why don't I see changes done in CTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

```
create table tab(id int);

insert into tab(id) values(1);

with x as (delete from tab where id = 1 returning id),
y as (select * from tab where id in (select id from x))
select * from y;

-- outputs a row with "1"
-- i need no rows returned
```

Why do I still see deleted row in `y` CTE subquery? `x` and `y` sections should be executed in sequential order since `y` depends on `x`. Could you please explain to me why I don't see changes from `x`? and what should I do to see them?

I'm not sure that it's related to isolation levels since everything is done in the same query => same transaction

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is documented in ["7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in `WITH`"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> (...)
>
> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each
>   other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates
>   actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with
>   the same snapshot (see [Chapter
>   13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they
>   cannot "see" one another's effects on the target tables. (...)
>
> (...)

To delete from the table and get an empty result with the schema of the table in one query just delete in a CTE and select from the table with a false `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH
cte
AS
(
DELETE FROM tab
       WHERE id = 1 
)
SELECT *
       FROM tab
       WHERE false;
```